# Barcode Generator

Tags: magento-1.9, barcode

Can anyone help me to make a **barcode** section or create **barcode dynamically** on product details page?

My client wants to show the barcode on product details page and it will be managed from the dashboard section.

Please check the attachment below.

[image: My client wants this type of barcode]

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using an extension by which you can create and print barcodes for your products.

Please have a look at these links:

https://www.boostmyshop.com/barcode-label.html

https://www.wyomind.com/stock-barcode-scanner-magento.html

https://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/product-barcode-label-generation

Optionally, you can use Zend Barcode library to create your custom module to fulfill your requirement.